# extending objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm kinda lost in getting the object extending to work. I have read dozens of sites related to this topic, but I'm still no wiser. It seems that everyone uses it's own approach to make this work, and so do I , I'm trying to find the best approach for extending/inheriting objects.

I am also aware that there are tons of frameworks/plugins out there to cover this functionality, but i'd just like to understand how it works in general. Not mentioning that most of these frameworks include lots of other stuff I may never use, hence I'm trying to make my own.

I was able to extend an object , everything seemed to be ok until I started adding methods to the target object. To understand the issue, please see the below example...

or just try this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xquqjzos/1/)

The thing is, that after initializing the new instance of `Rabbit` object, I wasn't able to access **Rabbit's** method `changeName`.
And I don't understand why it's happening, i.e why it doesn't recognize the method.

**[*]** Please see my updated code below (also the JFiddle), everything now seems to be working ok.

Can anoyne please advise, if this is a good approach or what am I missing?

```
var Class = (function(NewClass){
    if(NewClass.length != 0){
        var extend = function(target, source, args) {
            Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source).forEach(function(propName) {
                if(propName !== "Extend")
                {
                    Object.defineProperty(
                        target, propName,
                        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, propName)
                    );
                }
                if (typeof source[propName] !== 'undefined'){
                    delete source[propName];
                }
            });

            return target;
        };
        var inherit = function(source, args){
            var baseClass = Object.getPrototypeOf(this); 
            baseClass.prototype = extend.call(this, baseClass, source, args);
        };
        if(NewClass.Extend){
            var Class = function(){ //// New Class Constructor ////
                if(typeof NewClass.Extend === 'function'){
                    NewClass.Extend.apply(this, arguments);
                    inherit.call(this, NewClass.Extend);
                    console.log(NewClass)
                    inherit.call(this, NewClass, arguments);
                    if(NewClass.Initialize){
                        NewClass.Initialize.call(this, arguments);
                    }
                }
            };
            Class.prototype.constructor = Class;
            return Class; 
        }
    }
});

var Animal =(function(args){//// constructor ////
    var self = this;
    self.name = typeof args !== 'undefined' ? args.name : null;
    self.bags = 0;
});

var Rabbit = new Class({
    Extend: Animal ,
    Initialize: function(){
        console.log(this.name)
    },
    changeName: function(a){

        console.log(this.name)
    }
});


var LittleRabbit = new Rabbit({name: "LittleRabbit", type: "None"});
console.log(LittleRabbit instanceof Rabbit)
console.log(LittleRabbit)
LittleRabbit.changeName("alex");
```

Comment: first: you pass to `Class` object, but expect array, because try check `length` property

Comment: in `new Class` you pass object and in `Class` function you check if `args.length != 0` which evaluates to false as by default object prototype does not have `length` function

Comment: @ivarPrudnikov, you wrong :-) `args.length` is _undefined_ for object without this property, so `args.length != 0` always _true_, because `undefined != 0`

Comment: Also I might suggest [Douglas Crocford Classical Inheritance in JavaScript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html)

Comment: Ouch!! This hurts :D How could I miss it..

Comment: So, main error: you not add property from object that pass to `Class` function, you just check `Extend` and `Initialize` and miss others

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90536/discussion-between-grundy-and-ivarprudnikov).

Comment: yeah I just realized that these are missing...

Comment: @Alexus, also your `extend` function work wrong

Comment: could you please be more specific?

Comment: @Alexus, your `inherit` still wrong :-) you can't set prototype for object just assign _prototype_ property, so this function wrong. And also you again pass object to `Class` function, and again try check property `length` that usually missed in object, so your condition `if(NewClass.length != 0){` always _true_, because `undefined != 0`

Comment: @Alexus, for implementing inheritance - you just need do two things: first, call base function in constructor like `function A(){ Base.call(this)}`, second, set prototype like `A.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype)` this enough, but you try do something not clear and complicated with your `extend` and `inherit` functions

Comment: actually I took these functions from an example I found on internet while looking for a good practices in making extend like behavior in JS for objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90588/discussion-between-grundy-and-alexus).

Comment: @Alexus Please avoid extended discussions in comments. and let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90588/discussion-between-grundy-and-alexus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `extend` function work wrong, because [Object.getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) return *prototype*, so in more cases it *object*

```
var extend = function(source, args){
    var baseClass = Object.getPrototypeOf(this); 
    source.apply(this, args);

    //so here you just add property prototype to object, and this not same as set prototype to function.
    baseClass.prototype = Object.create(source.prototype);
};
```

So you can fix this like in snippet below:

```js
function Class(args) {
  if (arguments.length != 0) {
    var C = function() {
      if (typeof args.Extend == 'function') {
        args.Extend.apply(this, arguments)
      }
      if (args.Initialize) {
        args.Initialize.call(this);
      }
    };
    if (typeof args.Extend == 'function') {
      C.prototype = Object.create(args.Extend.prototype);
    }

    Object.keys(args).filter(function(el) {
      return ['Extend', 'Initialize'].indexOf(el) == -1
    }).forEach(function(el) {
      C.prototype[el] = args[el];
    });

    return C;
  }
};

var Animal = (function(args) { //// constructor ////
  var self = this;
  self.name = typeof args !== 'undefined' ? args.name : null;
  self.bags = 0;
});

var Rabbit = Class({
  Extend: Animal,
  Initialize: function() {
    console.log(this.name);
  },
  changeName: function(a) {
    this.name = a;
  }
});


var LittleRabbit = new Rabbit({
  name: "LittleRabbit",
  type: "None"
});
console.log(LittleRabbit instanceof Rabbit);
console.log(LittleRabbit instanceof Animal);
console.log(LittleRabbit.name);
LittleRabbit.changeName('new little rabbit');
console.log(LittleRabbit.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading the [MDN article detailing the JavaScript object model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model). It contains examples of "manually" subclassing:

```
function Employee() {
  this.name = "";
  this.dept = "general";
}

function Manager() {
  Employee.call(this);
  this.reports = [];
}
Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);

function WorkerBee() {
  Employee.call(this);
  this.projects = [];
}
WorkerBee.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype)
```

Translating your example to this style is simple:

```
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.bags = 0;
}

function Rabbit(name) {
  Animal.call(this, name);
  console.log(this.name);
}
Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Rabbit.prototype.changeName = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
};
```

Then you can easily run your example, modified a bit:

```
var LittleRabbit = new Rabbit("LittleRabbit");
console.log(LittleRabbit instanceof Rabbit)
console.log(LittleRabbit)
LittleRabbit.changeName("new name");
```

Once you understand this, I'd recommend not building your own class creation mechanism and just use [ES6 classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

```
class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.bags = 0;
  }
}

class Rabbit extends Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
    console.log(this.name);
  }

  changeName(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

You can see this example in the [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=true&code=class%20Animal%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor(name)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20this.bags%20%3D%200%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Rabbit%20extends%20Animal%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor(name)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20super(name)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this.name)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20changeName(name)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20name%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20LittleRabbit%20%3D%20new%20Rabbit(%22LittleRabbit%22)%3B%0Aconsole.log(LittleRabbit%20instanceof%20Rabbit)%0Aconsole.log(LittleRabbit)%0ALittleRabbit.changeName(%22new%20name%22)%3B%0A). Some browsers/js runtimes [natively support ES6 classes already](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/), but you can use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to translate your code to ES5 for environments that don't yet.

As an aside, there is actually more that needs to be done to subclass completely correctly. A more complete example (that may not work in all environments) is this:

```
function Animal() {}
function Rabbit() {
  Animal.call(this);
}
Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Rabbit.prototype.constructor = Rabbit;
Rabbit.__proto__ = Animal;
```

Comment: in your sample `console.log(LittleRabbit instanceof Animal)` - _false_

Comment: Grundy, you're right. I forgot to add `Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);`. I updated it to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

May ES6 class inheritance an option for you:

```
'use strict';
class Animal {
  constructor( name ) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  changeName( name ) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Rabbit extends Animal {
  constructor() {
    super( 'rabbit' );
  }
}

let littleRabbit = new Rabbit();

console.log( littleRabbit.name ); //log default name

littleRabbit.changeName( 'littleRabbit' ); //executing an method of animal class

console.log( littleRabbit.name ); //log changed name
```

You don't need the "overhead" for making OOP inheritance for old good javascript because there are "translators" out there which translate your es6 code to es5 code. For Example babel: https://babeljs.io/

I think it is worth to give it a try...