# Extending multiple objects/classess in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I have posted this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32763375/extending-objects-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment53393052_32763375) couple of days ago where I was looking for a good approach for making Extending Class like behaviour for JS objects.

With the help of all discussants,I was able to make the extend functionality to work. But since I can only extend a single class, I was wondering if multiple class/object extending is possible in JS.

I have tried to simulate this behaviour in below code, but unfortunately it doesn't really work as I would expect. The last object always overwrites the base class ( it's just a simple object where I'm storing all the objects that are used to extend )

As you can see below the :

```
[Rabbit] extends [WorldObject] , [Animal]
[BigRabbit] extends [Rabbit]
```

But for some reason , the `WorldObject` properties are always overwritten by `Animal`. I also know that this is the part

```
for(var c=0; c <= (NewClass.Extend.length - 1); c++){
                if(typeof NewClass.Extend[c] === 'function'){
                    MultiExtClass.prototype = Object.create(NewClass.Extend[c].prototype); 
                }
            }
```

which is causing that the `MultiExtClass` is being overwritten, instead of extending.

```js
"use strict"
 
 var CopyObjProps =(function(target, source){
  var getObjKeys = Object.keys || function(o) { 
   var keysArray = []; 
   for(var name in o) { 
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) 
      keysArray.push(name); 
   } 
   return keysArray; 
  };
  var ObjectPropsNames =  getObjKeys;

  ObjectPropsNames(source).filter(function(el) {
   return ['Extend', 'Initialize'].indexOf(el) == -1
  }).forEach(function(el) {
    target.prototype[el] = source[el];
  });
  
  return target;
 });
 
 var Extendable = (function(){
  this.extend = function(NewClass){
   var ExtClass = function() {
    if(typeof NewClass.Extend === 'function'){
     NewClass.Extend.apply(this, arguments);  
    }
    if(NewClass.Initialize){
     NewClass.Initialize.apply(this, arguments);  
    }
   };
   if(typeof NewClass.Extend === 'function'){
    ExtClass.prototype = Object.create(NewClass.Extend.prototype); 
   }
   
   CopyObjProps(ExtClass, NewClass);
   
   return ExtClass;
  }
 });
 
 var MultiExtendable = (function(){
  this.extend = function(NewClass){
   var MultiExtClass = function(args){
    for(var c=0; c <= (NewClass.Extend.length - 1); c++){
     if(typeof NewClass.Extend[c] === 'function'){
      NewClass.Extend[c].call(this, args);  
     }
    }
    if(NewClass.Initialize){
     NewClass.Initialize.call(this, args); 
    }
   };
   for(var c=0; c <= (NewClass.Extend.length - 1); c++){
    if(typeof NewClass.Extend[c] === 'function'){
     MultiExtClass.prototype = Object.create(NewClass.Extend[c].prototype); 
    }
   }
   CopyObjProps(MultiExtClass, NewClass);
   return MultiExtClass;
  }
 });
 
 var Class = (function(NewClass){
  if(arguments.length != 0){
   var self = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
   if(typeof NewClass.Extend === "function"){
    Extendable.call(self);
    return self.extend(NewClass);;
   }
   else if(typeof NewClass.Extend === "object"){
    MultiExtendable.call(self);
    return self.extend(NewClass);
   }
   else{
    var NotExtClass = function() { 
     if(typeof NewClass.Initialize === "function"){
      NewClass.Initialize.apply(NewClass, arguments);
     }
    };
    CopyObjProps(NotExtClass, NewClass);
    return NotExtClass;
   }
  }
 });
 
 var WorldObject = new Class({
  Initialize: function(args){
   console.log("WorldObject-initialized");
  },
  Haha: function(){},
  test: 4
 });
 
 var Animal =new Class({
  Initialize: function(args){
   console.log("Animal-initialized");
   this.setName(args.name)
  },
  setName: function(name){
   this.name = name || null;
   console.log("Animal-changed name :", this.name)
  },
  animal: 14
 });
 
 var Rabbit = new Class({
  Extend: [ WorldObject, Animal],
  Initialize: function(args){
   console.log("Rabbit-initialized ");
  },
  changeName: function(a){
   this.name = a;
   console.log("Rabbit-changed name :", this.name)
  },
  rabbit: 1
 });
 
 var BigRabbit = new Class({
  Extend: Rabbit,
  Initialize: function(args){
   console.log("BigRabbit-initialized ")
   this.changeName(args.name);
  },
  changeName: function(a){
   this.name = a;
   console.log("BigRabbit-changed name :", this.name)
  },
  alex: 7
 });
 
 var NewRabbit = new BigRabbit({name: "JustArabbit"});
 
 NewRabbit.changeName("RabbitTest");
 console.log(NewRabbit instanceof BigRabbit)
 console.log(NewRabbit instanceof Animal)
 console.log(NewRabbit instanceof Rabbit)
 console.log(NewRabbit instanceof WorldObject)
 console.log(NewRabbit)
```